# PL/SQL "wrong number or types of arguments" and "Statement ignored"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am keep getting wrong number or types of arguments in call to my procedure and statement ignored errors.

Here is my procedure

```
Procedure runCheck(p_runId    in out number,
                     p_runCheck in out FSS_RUN_TABLE%rowtype) is
    v_runId number := 0;

  Begin
    Begin
      select *
        into p_runCheck
        from FSS_RUN_TABLE
       where RUNOUTCOME = 'SUCCESS'
         and Trunc(RUNEND) = Trunc(sysdate);

    Exception
      when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        p_runId := RUNLOG_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
        insert into FSS_RUN_TABLE
          (RUNID, RUNSTART, RUNEND, RUNOUTCOME, REMARKS)
        values
          (p_runId, sysdate, null, null, 'RUN START');
    End;
  Exception
    when others then
      select RUNID
        into v_runId
        from FSS_RUN_TABLE
       where Trunc(RUNSTART) = Trunc(sysdate);
      update FSS_RUN_TABLE
         set RUNEND     = sysdate,
             RUNOUTCOME = 'FAILED',
             REMARKS    = 'RUN FAILED'
       where RUNID = v_runId;
  End;
```

Here is how I execute this procedure

```
Begin
       PKG_FSS_SETTLEMENT.runCheck;
End;
```

My FSS_RUN_TABLE contents 5 columns which are RUNID, RUNSTART, RUNEND, RUNOUTCOME, REMARKS

Don't understand why am I keeping get this error message? Please any answer would be helpful, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure expects parameters, they are mandatory (and you declared them "in/out").

```
declare

  l_runId number;
  l_runCheck FSS_RUN_TABLE%rowtype;

Begin
   PKG_FSS_SETTLEMENT.runCheck(
     p_runId => l_runId,
     p_runCheck => l_runCheck);
End;
```

But I am concerned about the code itself - what are you trying to achieve? Why did you separate the exceptions blocks? You can leave the one, and manage all the exceptions there.